# Android - CPU Utilization of website

Tags: android, cpu-usage, android-traceview

I have used commands like Top and also tools like Traceview to understand the cpu utilization of native android application. But, can we use these tools to track while running a website on device browser ? If possible please share me your ideas of how to do the same ....

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Top would still work, as it does not rely on the internals of the process to retrieve the CPU usage. Traceview would not, as it does.

The process you'll be watching is the browser, naturally.

Answer (score 0):

Trepn Profiler tool by Qualcomm may help in this. Please check

https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/performance-tools/trepn-profiler